# uitableview datasource reloading in wrong order swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` with a variety of buttons across the top of the screen, each button associated to a separate `UITableViewDataSource`. Every time one of these buttons are clicked, the table view's datasource is updated and the tableView gets a `.reloadData` method, which updates all the data within the `tableView`.

I also have a label in the cell that reflects `indexPath.row()`, meaning each row has 1, 2, 3, etc going down as many rows as there are in the table.

However, my problem is when the table is reloaded, the indexes are out of order. Sometimes it starts at 3, 1, 2, 4, etc. Sometimes it's 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, etc.

There is also an image in the tableView's Cell, which only shows up on the first 8 or so rows.

Here is my `func` for changing the `dataSource`. Note that all `dataSource`s are instantiated above in the ViewController. All dataSources are in pairs, land/sea, and are grouped together in a nested array, with each inset array holding two dataSources, thus the input of a `[DataSource` array. (`DataSource` is also a custom object inheriting from `UITableViewDataSource`)

```
func changeDataSource(ds: [DataSource]) -> DataSource {
        var idx = landOrSeaSegments.selectedSegmentIndex
        currentDS = ds

        //If Land segment is selected, show 'Land' datasource, else show 'Sea' datasource
        if showLandDS == true {
            idx = 0
            headerImage?.image = ds[idx].headerImage
            println("Y1 Land")
        } else {
            idx = 1
            headerImage?.image = ds[idx].headerImage
            println("Y1 Sea")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        return ds[idx]
    }
```

If anything is unclear please say so. I am a little inexperienced at asking these questions!

**EDIT**

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath in each database. They're all structured the same, with different values in the textArray and eventually the same with an array of images. for now the image is static.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YCell") as YCell
    var cellText = cell.dayDesc?.text //dayDesc is a custom label as an outlet in my YCell class.

    cell.dayNumberLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    cell.dayIcon?.image = UIImage(named: "icon")

    cellText = textArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you clearing out this label when the cell gets reused? A reused cell can appear in a different place in the table view.

Comment: Clearing out the label? Like setting it to nil?

Comment: Can you add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is caused because cells are reused. In your UITableViewCell subclass implement

```
func prepareForReuse() {
  self.textLabel.text = "" //Put your label name
}
```

Comment: That seems to work as son as I load it, however they do start to disappear after I scroll around on the table

Comment: Post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method please.